# WickedPdf stopped working on my local system

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm getting this error while generating pdf using wkhtmltopdf

```
undefined method `pdf_from_string' for #<WickedPdf:0x7f4b82a369c8>
```

my wicked_pdf.rb

```
WickedPdf.config = {

:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
:layout => "pdf.html",
:margin => {    :top=> 40,
                :bottom => 20,
                :left=> 30,
                :right => 30},
:header => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_header.html'}},
:footer => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_footer.html'}}
# :exe_path => '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'}
```

on command line

```
wkhtmltopdf google.com google.pdf
```

is working fine.

Comment: Why don't you add a ruby tag in your question  .. might help

Answer (score 0):

"pdf_from_string"  means, that it makes pdf from STRING.
So to make this method work it should recieve string.

```
<WickedPdf:0x7f4b82a369c8>  -  it is an object.
```

It should look like this:

```
pdf_from_string("<p>some html code</p>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get this message when calling `pdf_from_string` on the class itself, instead of an instance.

```
WickedPdf.pdf_from_string('<p>some html code</p>')
```

Will not work, however:

```
WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<p>some html code</>')
```

will, because `new` returns an instance, which you could then call `pdf_from_string` on.

This is the same as this:

```
pdf_generator = WickedPdf.new
pdf = pdf_generator.pdf_from_string('<p>some html code</p>')
```